# Casting struct to logic

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

This is related to my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23896809/casting-enum-to-logic). Consider the following module declaration:

```
module DFF(d, q, CLK, RESET);
 parameter W = 2;
 input  [W-1:0] d;                      
 input  CLK;                                
 input  RESET;      
 output logic [W-1:0]   q; 

//....
endmodule
```

What is the proper way of instantiating it where d and q are of struct type? Here is my struct type:

```
typedef struct { logic s1; logic s2} T_STATE;
```

I would like to instantiate the DFF for a T_STATE variable type:

```
T_STATE d, q;
DFF dff_inst (.d(d), .q(q), .CLK(CLK), .RESET(RESET));
```

I have unsuccessfully  tried the followings:

```
typedef logic [$bits(T_STATE) - 1 : 0] T_STATE_LOGIC; 
DFF dff_inst (.d(T_STATE_LOGIC'(d)), .q(T_STATE_LOGIC'(q)), .CLK(CLK), .RESET(RESET));
```

and

```
DFF dff_inst (.d({d}), .q({q}), .CLK(CLK), .RESET(RESET));
```

I need the code to be synthesizable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make it a struct of packed bits.

Change:

```
typedef struct { logic s1; logic s2} T_STATE;
```

to:

```
typedef struct packed { logic s1; logic s2;} T_STATE;
```

Your `DDF` can be instantiated as:

```
DFF dff_inst (.d(d), .q(q), .CLK(CLK), .RESET(RESET));
```

Note: you were missing a semicolon for `s2` in the struct definition.